# How to change node color in .dot file using pattern matching?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, visualization, dot

For example I have a [dot file](https://wolfr.am/zp54P15j) that describe a decision tree or binary tree

[image]

In the file, the color of node is always gold, so I try to change it according the number in `"cep_s\*_\*"`, in this image it's 91.

[image]

First I use `StringMatchQ` to check if No.136 line match a pattern.

```
txt = Import["https://wolfr.am/zp54P15j", "Lines"];
p = StartOfLine ~~ Whitespace ~~ "\"cep_s" ~~ DigitCharacter ~~ "_" ~~
    DigitCharacter .. ~~ "*fillcolor=" ~~ "gold" ~~ "];";
StringMatchQ[txt[[136]], p]
(*True*)
```

Then I can use this rule to map all the node to change their color according to their number in `"cep_s\*_\*"`.

Just for simple, here use three colors.

```
txt = Import["https://wolfr.am/zp54P15j", "String"];
colors = {"black", "yellow", "red"};
txtNew = StringReplace[txt, 
   a : (StartOfLine ~~ Whitespace ~~ "\"cep_s" ~~ DigitCharacter ~~ 
        "_") ~~ b : DigitCharacter .. ~~ c : "*fillcolor=" ~~ 
     d : "gold" ~~ e : "];" :> 
    a <> b <> c <> colors[[Mod[ToExpression[b], 3] + 1]] <> e];
txtNew == txt
(*True*)
```

`txtNew` is equal `txt`, nothing change. I don't know what is wrong.
Thank you for your reply!

***PS:*** Using this code in terminal can visualize(using [graphviz](http://graphviz.org/)) the decision tree like the top image

> dot -Tpng test.dot -o test.png
>
> dot -Tpdf test.dot -o test.pdf

Comment: `ToExpression[b] %3 + 1` should be `Mod[ToExpression[b], 3] + 1`?

Comment: yes, i used python grammar... thanks fot point out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `c : Shortest[___ ~~ "fillcolor="]` instead of `c : "*fillcolor="`:

```
txt = Import["https://wolfr.am/zp54P15j", "String"];
colors = {"black", "yellow", "red"};
txtNew = StringReplace[txt, 
   a : (StartOfLine ~~ Whitespace ~~ "\"cep_s" ~~ DigitCharacter ~~  "_") ~~ 
   b : DigitCharacter .. ~~ 
   c : Shortest[___ ~~ "fillcolor="] ~~ 
   d : "gold" ~~ e : "];" :> a <> b <> c <> colors[[Mod[ToExpression[b], 3] + 1]] <> e];

StringCases[txtNew, StartOfLine ~~ Whitespace ~~ "\"cep_s" ~~ DigitCharacter ~~
      "_" ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ "];"] //  Short[#, 5] &
```

[image]

**Note:** `StringMatchQ` allows abbreviated string patterns containing `"*"` but in `StringReplace`, `StringCases`, `StringPosition` etc `"*"` in the pattern `"*fillcolor="` is taken literally. Using a simpler example:

```
StringMatchQ["abc  def", "*def"]
```

> True

```
StringReplace["abc  def", "*def" :> "XX" <> "1"]
```

> "abc  def"

```
StringReplace["abc  def", ___ ~~ "def" :> "XX" <> "1"]
```

> "XX1"

```
StringCases["abc  def", "*def"]
```

> {}

```
StringCases["abc  def", ___ ~~ "def"]
```

> {"abc  def"}

Comment: like a tutorial. This problem puzzle me a half day. Thank you give such a detailed answer and figure out the difference between these String* function